# Stick text to image in jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want the text to stick to the image from it's left side and change the text direction to rtl but when I try  `style = TextStyle(textDirection = TextDirection.Rtl)` it doesnt work.

Here's the whole code:

```
Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
        ) {
            IconButton(
                onClick = { navController.popBackStack() },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.Start)
                    .padding(top = 8.dp)
            ) {
                Icon(
                    Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
                    contentDescription = "Back",
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
                )
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))`

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(vertical = 4.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start, // Set horizontal arrangement to Start
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                // Left side with text
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .weight(1f) // Occupy remaining space
                ) {
                    Text(
                        product.name,
                        fontSize = 24.sp,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                        style = TextStyle(textDirection = TextDirection.Rtl)
                    )

                    Text(
                        text = product.manufacturer,
                        fontSize = 16.sp,
                        style = TextStyle(textDirection = TextDirection.Rtl),
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 16.dp, top = 4.dp) // Adjusted padding
                    )

                    Row(
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            "${product.rating}/100",
                            fontSize = 16.sp,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium.copy(
                                color = ratingColor,
                                textDirection = TextDirection.Rtl
                            ),
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 8.dp), // Add padding to the end (right side)
                            textAlign = TextAlign.End
                        )
                        RatingCircle(ratingColor = ratingColor)
                    }
                }

                // Right side with the image
                Image(
                    painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(model = product.imageUrl),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(150.dp)
                        .clip(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium)
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

The text should be to the left of the image and stick to it with the image on the right side of the box.

I tried a lot of rtl modifiers but they dont seem to affect the direction of the text. and playing with the padding and parameters to get the text closer to the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand why the `TextDirection.Rtl` doesn't work, you need to set a background
color for your text

```
                Text(
                    "product.name",
                    modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Cyan),
                    fontSize = 24.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    style = TextStyle(textDirection = TextDirection.Rtl ),
                )
```

[image]
As you can see, the text size has been limited according to your text length, so to make `TextDirection.Rtl` work, you need to add `modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()`, then the text will have enough space to display Right to left.

```
            Text(
                "product.name",
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().background(Color.Cyan),
                fontSize = 24.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                style = TextStyle(textDirection = TextDirection.Rtl ),
            )
```

[image]

Comment: Im trying to put a box near the text but using fillmaxwidth doesnt work on it: Box( modifier = Modifier .size(20.dp) .clip(CircleShape) .background(color = ratingColor).fillMaxWidth()) how can I get this box near the text